# Which one is correct? earth treasures , or earth's treasures

Tags: possessives, apostrophe

I want to know which one is correct?

We illuminate earth treasures.
or
we illuminate earth's treasures.

Answer (score 1):

The treasures belong to the earth so it should be earth's. The 's show possession.

Unless what you're saying is that you only illuminate things that most people would consider to be "earth treasures," which is not what I think you're saying. I think you're saying treasures that belong to the earth or emanate from the earth.